# Need a chome mobile to auto reload a tab/page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I have a google spreadsheet that is accessed via the web using an Android tablet. The android tablet uses Chrome, the mobile version obviously. The desktop version of Chrome has an extension for auto reload, currently mobile doesn't support extensions. Does anyone have an idea as to how I can accomplish this? I tried a bookmark script, works on my desktop but not the mobile version. I have to be able to access the bookmark from the page and can't do it on mobile. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

A page with an `<iframe>` and a `<button>` to reload its contents?